# Where is the implementation of abi::__cxa_demangle in libstdc++

Tags: c++, g++, libstdc++, demangler

GNU's libstdc++ provides the function `abi::__cxa_demangle`. The declaration of this function can be found in gcc / libstdc++-v3 / libsupc++ / cxxabi.h ([code repository here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3))

I am interested in reviewing the implementation of this function but I am unable to find a definition in the aforementioned repository. There is one definition in [gcc / libiberty](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libiberty) but, from what I can gather, this library is only used in a few GNU programs and mostly decommissioned (or so claims Wikipedia).

I managed to dig up some old [discussion threads](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/libstdc++/2004-02/msg00353.html) from 2003 that mention replacing the `libstdc++-v3 demangler` with the `libiberty demangler` which further confused me.

Here are my questions:

1. Does a `libstdc++-v3 demangler` still exist (as mentioned in the thread linked to above)?
2. Is the `libiberty demangler` used in `libstdc++-v3`?
3. Where can I find the implementation of `abi::__cxa_demangle`

Comment: Easy googled for llvm https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi/blob/master/src/cxa_demangle.cpp

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/cp-demangle.c#L6685